# Scroll bars on isotope container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I have my body element assigned with `overflow:hidden;` and added `overflow:auto;` in an attempt to add scroll bars just to the container div since i need a locked header and footer bordering my container div.

I've tried putting it in a div of its own. I've also tried:

```
var $container = $(".container");
$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true,
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: { 
       columnWidth : 60 
     } 
   }).css('overflow','auto');
```

None of which seems to work. Any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have an example on codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i've understood this correctly, but is this what you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrissp26/ywQyg/

If so the important bits in the jsfiddle code above are the overrides in the css:

```
#container {
    height: 300px !important;   
    overflow: auto !important;  
}
```

Comment: The fiddle was very useful to me, as it shows that the container needs to be position:relative. In your version this seems to happen automatically, for me I needed to set that style manually and it worked like a charm!